# How to NOT show the picker for minutes in showTimePicker?

Tags: flutter, dart

Before Flutter v1.7.8 update, showTimePicker would show the HOUR only, but after the update a fix was implemented to show the minutes after the hour is picked.

In our current project, we don't need to show the minutes, we ask the user to pick the time only.

How do we NOT SHOW the minutes picker, after the hour is picked?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you find any solution for this? @UP3

Comment: We customized the widget code, creating a new one with a different name. Not ideal, but works for our purpose.